# React: How to make selected options not to show in input field of Material UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I would like not to have the labels of the selected Options in the Input field:
It can probably be addressed in the renderInput property but I dont know how. I know there is the limitTags prop but the options would still be displayed in the input field when it is selected.
here is an example code:

Any suggestions?

```
import React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank';
import CheckBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBox';

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;

export default function CheckboxesTags() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          {option.title}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      style={{ width: 500 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" label="Checkboxes" placeholder="Favorites" />
      )}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
  { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
  { title: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: 'Pulp Fiction', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', year: 2003 },
  { title: 'The Good, the Bad and the Ugly', year: 1966 },
  { title: 'Fight Club', year: 1999 },
  { title: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring', year: 2001 },
  { title: 'Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back', year: 1980 },
  { title: 'Forrest Gump', year: 1994 }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this prop to your <AutoComplete renderTags={() => null} />
This will make the autoComplete not to render the tags inside of your TextField.